typescript append html element to html
I am trying to create a dynamic html element from typescript to be  displayed on html.
on my .ts file, my code is like this:
const displayContent = document.getElementById("display-content") as HTMLOutputElement;

var displayVariable = "";

videoArr.forEach(data => {
    displayVariable += "<h1>"+data.title + "</h1>"+"<p>"+data.description +"</p></hr></br>";

});
displayContent.textContent = displayVariable;

on my html file is like: <div id="display-content"></div>
but the output is not what I have expected:
<h1>Book 1 Water</h1><p>Learn the water bending</p></hr></br><h1>Book 2 Earth</h1><p>Learn the earth bending</p></hr></br><h1>Book 3 Fire</h1><p>Learn the fire bending</p></hr></br>

it shows the html code as the output and it didn't render the DOM. any idea?

You need to use displayContent.innerHTML to render the string as html. textContent specifically renders text only
